# How to keep my application always on top of the task stack?

Tags: android, stack, always-on-top

As title, how to keep my application always on top of task stack?
for example, when the alarm clock is popping up, my application(apk) is still on top of the screen.

Thanks very much!

Comment: Bad idea for android application design..

Comment: If you're trying to do this you're building poor design at best, malware at worst.  Rethink your goals.

Comment: Thanks for reply, but it's a requirement...Not my design.

Comment: Who cares why its required, its a valid question and stop wasting his time by asking such things.  His customer or boss may be telling him what he has to do as he mentioned in his comment - its a requirement.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK there's no way to do it.

What if the user receives a call? Would you like your application to hide it?

Comment: First, thanks for your reply.
In my case, I insert(remove) the SIM card in case phone is powered on, and the device will pop up a alarm dialog, this popup dialog shall always stay in the front at any other widgets/application screens.

So I want the other widgets/application that may pop up to push to the second level in the task stack.

But my problem is "How to change the application level in task stack", even if I can receive the event of insert(remove) SIM card.

Comment: @user1101466: Fortunately, what you want is not supported via the Android SDK.

Comment: But why the incoming call can be always on top of screen, even if the alarm clock is popping up at the same time?

Comment: This must be an OS feature. I don't know for sure try searching in incoming calls source code